# Iterating on Two generators with different length, with one wrapped around

Tags: python, list, dictionary, generator

I can't seem to make this happen with my brain no matter what I try but there must be a way to map with a generator function.

For example, if I want to multiply each member in the list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] with the corresponding member in the list [1,2,3] so after the [1,2,3] list runs out it would restart:

```
   [1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10]

x  [1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3  1 ]
------------------------------------
   [1  4  9  4  10 18 7  16 27 10]
```

How would you do this given you don't know the length of the [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) is your friend.  One way to do this would be to use `itertools.cycle` to loop over the second list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = range(1, 11)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> b = itertools.cycle([1,2,3])
>>> b
<itertools.cycle object at 0x1004be830>
>>> ans = [i*j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
>>> ans
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18, 7, 16, 27, 10]
```

which takes advantage of the fact that `zip` stops drawing terms when `a` runs out.

Comment: @ValentineBondar: Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark on the left if this solved your problem.

Comment: An alternative to the list comprehension would be  `itertools.imap()` together with `operator.mul()`: `imap(mul, a, cycle([1, 2, 3]))`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have random access than iterate over the first list and access the other elements by the first index modulo the other lists length.

If you only can iterate, iterate the first and have an iterator for the second that you restart every time it hits the second lists end.

If it really has to be done with a generator, than you need two: The outer yields the products of the first lists elements with the values of the second generator, which yields the second lists values and starts over at their end.

Comment: Could you give me simple examples in code of each type please? I'm still new at python and can't visualize it too easily...

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mark your question with the python tag. So I thought it is a more general programming question. My Python experience is way to long a ago. Consider retagging your question with the python tag and I'm sure someone else will help out.